# Constraining trajectory onto empirical manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

I am trying to define the dynamics of a system to follow a specific trajectory in the state space indicated by a point cloud/previous measurements/observations.

Let us consider a simple example:
In the following figure, I want my trajectory to start from one green circle and end at the second green circle and follow the trajectory indicated by the red points.

[image: point cloud of observations]

The system will follow some baseline simple dynamics (indicated here by the orange line) that ensures that the second point will be reached, and at every timestep I'd like to add some penalty cost that will drive the system towards the lower dimensional manifold indicated by the red points.

So I would like to be able to set some cost that maximizes the projection of the trajectory on the said empirical manifold.

My problem is that most manifold learning methods, identify a lower dimensional manifold, but they only return lower dimensional co-ordinates of the point cloud to a lower dimensional space. Here, I would need either the geodesic of the learnt manifold so I can constrain my trajectory to follow the geodesic, or at least some mapping that would transform a random point of the ambient space to the lower dimensional space.

Has anyone seen any method or publication that performs what I describe here?
or does anyone has any indication of what to read and how to proceed onward?

Comment: You just want it to follow approximatively the red points I suppose ?

Comment: Yep exactly! We want to approximately follow the red dots which are by themselves noisy measurements of a trajectory

Comment: Have you tried to fit a closed curve to those points? Say, using splines?

Comment: Fitting to a curve seems like a fair idea. It may also of help to know if the base dynamics is given or may be chosen. The data given is that just the cloud of points and the two green points? And then we should find a base-dynamics as well as constraints assuring that we go from one green point and (converge) towards the other, staying close to the cloud?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Background, context and motivation always help. If this is a robotics problem, some form of smoothness in the trajectory may be required. But the OP provided no such details, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is one possible path: Let $R_1,...,R_N$ denote the points in the cloud, $A$ the aimed point and $r$ the current point then you may calculate a 'local' center of gravity $C$ of the cloud in the vicinity of $r$ by taking the average of $R_i$ with respect to a probability vector which could be chosen e.g. as (with $\sigma>0$):
$$ const \times \exp ( - \sum_i (R_i-r)^2 / \sigma^2 )$$

You may chose a vector field like: $v(r) = A-r + \lambda (C-r)$ and solve $\dot{r}=v(r)$. I made a test for 1000 points randomly distributed on the annulus $0.95<x^2+y^2 < 1.05$. I chose $\lambda=25$ and $\sigma^2=0.05$ and it worked out pretty well.

The first term $A-r$ just directs towards the aimed for point. The other term $\lambda (C-r)$ drifts towards the 'local' center of gravity of the constraint cloud and $\sigma$ is the spread on which compute this local center.

Choosing $\lambda$ large gives a strong constraint but gives a 'bumpy' ride and sometimes  block the trajectory at some isolated point in the cloud. Choosing $\sigma$ small is good if you have a very dense point set in the cloud. There is some trade off between
these aspects. Also this simple approach may get stuck in some local minimum distance to A (notably if your curve for the cloud is not convex).